# In Rx, how to group latest items after a period of time?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Sorry if the title isn't very clear, I couldn't think of anything better...

I'm receiving user input in the form of an `IObservable<char>`, and I'd like to transform it to an `IObservable<char[]>`, by grouping the chars every time the user stops typing for more than 1 second. So, for instance, if the input is as follows:

```
h
e
l
l
o
(pause)
w
o
r
l
d
(pause)
!
(pause)
```

I'd like the output observable to be:

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
['!']
```

I suspect the solution is fairly simple, but I can't find the right approach... I tried to use `Buffer`, `GroupByUntil`, `Throttle` and a few others, to no avail.

Any idea would be welcome!

---

EDIT: I've got something that almost works:

```
        _input.Buffer(() => _input.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
              .ObserveOnDispatcher()
              .Subscribe(OnCompleteInput);
```

But I need the delay to be reset every time a new character is typed...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Buffer` and `Throttle` would be enough, if your source is hot.  To make it hot, you can use `.Publish().RefCount()` to ensure you only end up with one subscription to the source.

```
IObservable<IList<T>> BufferWithInactivity<T>(this IObservable<T> source,
                                              TimeSpan dueTime)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    //defer dueTime checking to Throttle
    var hot = source.Publish().RefCount();
    return hot.Buffer(() => hot.Throttle(dueTime));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great and it's much more elegant than my solution. Actually my source is already hot (it's a `Subject<T>` that I feed from input events); I'm not sure what the impact of using `Publish().RefCount()` is...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque If your source is already hot, I believe Publish/RefCount will just be some wasted wrapper layers.  If you want to use this as a general-case function, I'd probably just leave them unless they are shown to be a problem in your application.  If you use it just this once, change the parameter to `hotSource` and leave a note in the doc comments and you should be safe to remove Publish/RefCount.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution:

```
        Func<IObservable<char>> bufferClosingSelector =
            () =>
            _input.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                  .Catch(Observable.Return('\0'))
                  .Where(i => i == '\0');
        _input.Buffer(bufferClosingSelector)
              .ObserveOnDispatcher()
              .Subscribe(OnCompleteInput);
```

Basically, the `bufferClosingSelector` pushes something whenever a timeout occurs, which closes the current buffer. There's probably a simpler and more elegant way, but it works... I'm open to better suggestions ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension some time ago to do what you're after - `BufferWithInactivity`.

Here it is:

```
public static IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> BufferWithInactivity<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source,
    TimeSpan inactivity,
    int maximumBufferSize)
{
    return Observable.Create<IEnumerable<T>>(o =>
    {
        var gate = new object();
        var buffer = new List<T>();
        var mutable = new SerialDisposable();
        var subscription = (IDisposable)null;
        var scheduler = Scheduler.ThreadPool;

        Action dump = () =>
        {
            var bts = buffer.ToArray();
            buffer = new List<T>();
            if (o != null)
            {
                o.OnNext(bts);
            }
        };

        Action dispose = () =>
        {
            if (subscription != null)
            {
                subscription.Dispose();
            }
            mutable.Dispose();
        };

        Action<Action<IObserver<IEnumerable<T>>>> onErrorOrCompleted =
            onAction =>
            {
                lock (gate)
                {
                    dispose();
                    dump();
                    if (o != null)
                    {
                        onAction(o);
                    }
                }
            };

        Action<Exception> onError = ex =>
            onErrorOrCompleted(x => x.OnError(ex));

        Action onCompleted = () => onErrorOrCompleted(x => x.OnCompleted());

        Action<T> onNext = t =>
        {
            lock (gate)
            {
                buffer.Add(t);
                if (buffer.Count == maximumBufferSize)
                {
                    dump();
                    mutable.Disposable = Disposable.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    mutable.Disposable = scheduler.Schedule(inactivity, () =>
                    {
                        lock (gate)
                        {
                            dump();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };

        subscription =
            source
                .ObserveOn(scheduler)
                .Subscribe(onNext, onError, onCompleted);

        return () =>
        {
            lock (gate)
            {
                o = null;
                dispose();
            }
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However it's not exactly "simpler" than my solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work.  It's not nearly as concise as your solution, as it implements the logic through a class instead of extension methods, but it might be a better way to do it.  In short: every time you get a `char`, add it to a `List` and (re)start a timer that will expire in one second; when the timer expires, notify our subscribers with the `List` as an array and reset the state so it's ready for next time.

```
    class Breaker : IObservable<char[]>, IObserver<char>
    {
        List<IObserver<char[]>> observers = new List<IObserver<char[]>>();
        List<char> currentChars;
        DispatcherTimer t;
        public Breaker(IObservable<char> source)
        {
            source.Subscribe(this);
            t = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1) };
            t.Tick += TimerOver;
            currentChars = new List<char>();
        }
        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<char[]> observer)
        {
            observers.Add(observer);
            return null; //TODO return a useful IDisposable
        }
        public void OnCompleted()
        {
            //TODO implement completion logic
        }
        public void OnError(Exception e)
        {
            //TODO implement error logic
        }
        public void OnNext(char value)
        {
            currentChars.Add(value);
            t.Start();
        }
        void TimerOver(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            char[] chars = currentChars.ToArray();
            foreach (var obs in observers)
                obs.OnNext(chars);
            currentChars.Clear();
            t.Stop();
        }
    }
```